# Iterating through a badly designed API where object keys consist of text and numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

Currently working on a web app used to search for drink recipes. The idea is to search for a drink and have the name, ingredients and measurements displayed to the user. I am struggling to find an efficient way to iterate through the API response as they do not come back as an array. Below is an example response.

```
dateModified :"2015-08-18 14:54:32"   
idDrink:"11668"    
strAlcoholic:"Alcoholic
strCategory:"Ordinary Drink"
strDrink: "Long Island Tea"
strDrinkThumb:  "https://www.thecocktaildb.com/images/media/drink/ywxwqs1439906072.jpg"
strGlass: "Highball glass"
strIBA:null
strIngredient1: "Vodka"
strIngredient2:"Light rum"
strIngredient3:"Gin" 
strIngredient4:"Tequila"  
strIngredient5: "Lemon"
strIngredient6: "Coca-Cola" 
strIngredient7:""
strIngredient8:""
strIngredient9:""
strIngredient10:""
strIngredient11:""
strIngredient12:""
strIngredient13:""
strIngredient14:""
strIngredient15:""
strInstructions: 
"Combine all ingredients (except cola) and pour over ice in a highball glass. Add the splash of cola for color. Decorate with a slice of lemon and serve." 
strMeasure1:"1/2 oz "
strMeasure2:"1/2 oz "
strMeasure3: "1/2 oz "
strMeasure4: "1/2 oz "
strMeasure5:"Juice of 1/2 "
strMeasure6:"1 splash "
strMeasure7:" "
strMeasure8:" "
strMeasure9:" "
strMeasure10:" "
strMeasure11:" "
strMeasure12:" "
strMeasure13:" "
strMeasure14:" "
strMeasure15:" "
strVideo: null
```

The goal is to map some of the information to a table. Is there an iterative way to clean this up so that only ingredients with values are returned? Or is the best solution to create a separate file for formatting the ingredients?

Currently, the path of least resistance I can think of is creating the following 15 times: `strIngredient1 !=""`.

Below is the API call:

```
$('#drinkSearch').click(function(){
  var word = document.getElementById("sbar").value;

  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(word)
  $.getJSON("https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s="+ word, function(Result) {
    console.log(Result)
    Result.drinks.forEach(function(ingredients){
       var ing1 = ingredients.strIngredient1;

       console.log(ing1);
    })
  });
});
```

Comment: It looks to me like you get an array of "drinks" back, with a number of named fields that you want to map in some way.  It would be useful if you showed one complete response as JSON (not a link to an image) and what you want to map it to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The API returns an object for each drink with keys like `strIngredient1` through `strIngredient15`, `strMeasure1` through `strMeasure15`, etc. — indeed badly designed.

You can gather all these in an array. There are two different approaches of handling empty values. You can either **simply filter empty values** or **match measures to their ingredients**:

### Simply filter empty values

These approaches just remove empty values from each to-be-built array. This can lead to inconsistencies since the `strMeasure` keys actually depend on the `strIngredient` keys, *positionally*. Look for the **matching** approach below to fix that.

Another issue is that the ingredients and measures may be out-of-order sometimes. The **matching** approach doesn’t have this issue.

```
Result.drinks.forEach((drink) => {
  const drinkEntries = Object.entries(drink),
    ingredientsArray = drinkEntries
      .filter(([key, value]) => key.startsWith("strIngredient") && value && value.trim())
      .map(([key, value]) => value),
    measuresArray = drinkEntries
      .filter(([key, value]) => key.startsWith("strMeasure") && value && value.trim())
      .map(([key, value]) => value);

  console.log("Ingredients:", ingredientsArray);
  console.log("Measures:", measuresArray);
});
```

In the [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), `key.startsWith("strIngredient")` ensures that you get the right fifteen keys, and `&& value && value.trim()` ensures that the value is neither `null`, nor empty, nor just whitespace (hence [`trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)). All three variations are used randomly.

A less redundant form could look like this:

```
Result.drinks.forEach((drink) => {
  const drinkEntries = Object.entries(drink),
    [
      ingredientsArray,
      measuresArray
    ] = [
      "strIngredient",
      "strMeasure"
    ].map((keyName) => drinkEntries
      .filter(([key, value]) => key.startsWith(keyName) && value && value.trim())
      .map(([key, value]) => value));

  console.log("Ingredients:", ingredientsArray);
  console.log("Measures:", measuresArray);
});
```

### Match measures to their ingredients

This approach first builds two arrays for `strIngredient`s and `strMeasure`s. The numeric keys are extracted with `parseInt(key.slice(keyName.length))`. [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)ing several `{key: value}` objects onto an array, where `key`s are numeric, means building an array with those numeric keys and those values.<sup>1</sup>

Then the values are filtered such that they remain if *any* value with the *same index* is non-empty.

```
Result.drinks.forEach((drink) => {
  const drinkEntries = Object.entries(drink),
    // This part build arrays out of the two sets of keys
    [
      ingredientsArray,
      measuresArray
    ] = [
      "strIngredient",
      "strMeasure"
    ].map((keyName) => Object.assign([], ...drinkEntries
        .filter(([key, value]) => key.startsWith(keyName))
        .map(([key, value]) => ({[parseInt(key.slice(keyName.length))]: value})))),

    // This part filters empty values based on the ingredients
    {
      finalIngredients,
      finalMeasures
    } = ingredientsArray.reduce((results, value, index) => {
      if(value && value.trim() || measuresArray[index] && measuresArray[index].trim()){
        results.finalIngredients.push(value);
        results.finalMeasures.push(measuresArray[index]);
      }

      return results;
    }, {
      finalIngredients: [],
      finalMeasures: []
    }),

    // Optional: zip both arrays
    ingredientsWithMeasures = finalIngredients
      .map((value, index) => [finalMeasures[index], value]);

  // Output
  console.log("Ingredients:", finalIngredients);
  console.log("Measures:", finalMeasures);

  console.log("All ingredients and measures:\n", ingredientsWithMeasures
    .map(([measure, ingredient]) => `${(measure || "").trim()} ${(ingredient || "").trim()}`)
    .join("\n"));
});
```

---

<sup>1</sup>: Building an array from objects often also works with [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), but it requires a `length` property as well. Instead of calculating that, I just went ahead and used `Object.assign` instead.

Comment: Thank for the amazing answer! Definitely shows a nice way of handling annoying bad API responses and has helped me greatly.

Answer (score 0):

I like Xufox's answer, here's another possibility to tame that API, with a hardcoded call for a `manhattan` :)  The idea here is to marshal various things into a final `recipe` that contains the useful data.

NB I refactored this to show how you could (and maybe should) extract your mapping into a separate function.

```js
const word = 'manhattan';
const url = `https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=${word}`;


$.getJSON(url, (result) => {
  const recipes = result.drinks.map(extractRecipe);
  console.log(recipes);
})

// do your mapping in a defined function.
function extractRecipe(drink) {
  const recipe = {
    name: drink.strDrink,
    glass: drink.strGlass,
    instructions: drink.strInstructions,
    thumbnail: drink.strDrinkThumb
  };

  Object.keys(drink)
    .filter(key => key.substring(0, 13) === 'strIngredient')
    .filter(key => drink[key].trim())
    .reduce((ingredients, ingredient) => ingredients.concat(ingredient), [])
    .forEach((key, index) => {
      let ingIndex = index + 1;
      recipe[drink[key]] = drink[`strMeasure${ingIndex}`];
    })
  return recipe;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution can be:

```
result.drinks.forEach(function(ingredients){
   var ing = Object.keys(ingredients).reduce(function(a, ele) {
       if (ele.startsWith('strIngredient') && ingredients[ele].trim() != '') {
           if (!a[ingredients.strDrink]) a[ingredients.strDrink] = [];
           a[ingredients.strDrink].push(ingredients[ele]);
       }
       return a;
   }, {});
   console.log(Object.keys(ing)[0] + ': ' + ing[Object.keys(ing)[0]].join(', '));
```

})

```js
var result= {
    "drinks": [{
        "idDrink": "12734",
        "strDrink": "Chocolate Drink",
        "strVideo": null,
        "strCategory": "Cocoa",
        "strIBA": null,
        "strAlcoholic": "Non alcoholic",
        "strGlass": "Coffee mug",
        "strInstructions": "Melt the bar in a small amount of boiling water. Add milk. Cook over low heat, whipping gently (with a whisk, i would assume) until heated well. Don't let it boil! Serve in coffee mug.",
        "strDrinkThumb": "https:\/\/www.thecocktaildb.com\/images\/media\/drink\/q7w4xu1487603180.jpg",
        "strIngredient1": "Chocolate",
        "strIngredient2": "Milk",
        "strIngredient3": "Water",
        "strIngredient4": "",
        "strIngredient5": "",
        "strIngredient6": "",
        "strIngredient7": "",
        "strIngredient8": "",
        "strIngredient9": "",
        "strIngredient10": "",
        "strIngredient11": "",
        "strIngredient12": "",
        "strIngredient13": "",
        "strIngredient14": "",
        "strIngredient15": "",
        "strMeasure1": "125 gr",
        "strMeasure2": "3\/4 L ",
        "strMeasure3": "",
        "strMeasure4": "",
        "strMeasure5": "",
        "strMeasure6": "",
        "strMeasure7": "",
        "strMeasure8": "",
        "strMeasure9": "",
        "strMeasure10": "",
        "strMeasure11": "",
        "strMeasure12": "",
        "strMeasure13": "",
        "strMeasure14": "",
        "strMeasure15": "",
        "dateModified": "2017-02-20 15:06:20"
    }, {
        "idDrink": "12736",
        "strDrink": "Drinking Chocolate",
        "strVideo": null,
        "strCategory": "Cocoa",
        "strIBA": null,
        "strAlcoholic": "Non alcoholic",
        "strGlass": "Coffee mug",
        "strInstructions": "Heat the cream and milk with the cinnamon and vanilla bean very slowly for 15-20 minutes. (If you don't have any beans add 1-2 tsp of vanilla after heating). Remove the bean and cinnamon. Add the chocolate. Mix until fully melted. Serve topped with some very dense fresh whipped cream. Serves 1-2 depending upon how much of a glutton you are. For a richer chocolate, use 4 oz of milk, 4 oz of cream, 4 oz of chocolate. Serve in coffee mug.",
        "strDrinkThumb": "https:\/\/www.thecocktaildb.com\/images\/media\/drink\/u6jrdf1487603173.jpg",
        "strIngredient1": "Heavy cream",
        "strIngredient2": "Milk",
        "strIngredient3": "Cinnamon",
        "strIngredient4": "Vanilla",
        "strIngredient5": "Chocolate",
        "strIngredient6": "Whipped cream",
        "strIngredient7": "",
        "strIngredient8": "",
        "strIngredient9": "",
        "strIngredient10": "",
        "strIngredient11": "",
        "strIngredient12": "",
        "strIngredient13": "",
        "strIngredient14": "",
        "strIngredient15": "",
        "strMeasure1": "2 oz ",
        "strMeasure2": "6-8 oz ",
        "strMeasure3": "1 stick ",
        "strMeasure4": "1 ",
        "strMeasure5": "2 oz finely chopped dark ",
        "strMeasure6": "Fresh ",
        "strMeasure7": " ",
        "strMeasure8": " ",
        "strMeasure9": " ",
        "strMeasure10": " ",
        "strMeasure11": " ",
        "strMeasure12": "",
        "strMeasure13": "",
        "strMeasure14": "",
        "strMeasure15": "",
        "dateModified": "2017-02-20 15:06:13"
    }, {
        "idDrink": "12690",
        "strDrink": "Lassi - A South Indian Drink",
        "strVideo": null,
        "strCategory": "Other\/Unknown",
        "strIBA": null,
        "strAlcoholic": "Non alcoholic",
        "strGlass": "Highball Glass",
        "strInstructions": "Blend in a blender for 3 seconds. Lassi is one of the easiest things to make, and there are many ways of making it. Basically, it is buttermilk (yoghurt whisked with water), and you can choose almost any consistency that you like, from the thinnest to the thickest. Serve cold.",
        "strDrinkThumb": "https:\/\/www.thecocktaildb.com\/images\/media\/drink\/iq6scx1487603980.jpg",
        "strIngredient1": "Yoghurt",
        "strIngredient2": "Water",
        "strIngredient3": "Cumin seed",
        "strIngredient4": "Salt",
        "strIngredient5": "Mint",
        "strIngredient6": "",
        "strIngredient7": "",
        "strIngredient8": "",
        "strIngredient9": "",
        "strIngredient10": "",
        "strIngredient11": "",
        "strIngredient12": "",
        "strIngredient13": "",
        "strIngredient14": "",
        "strIngredient15": "",
        "strMeasure1": "1\/2 cup plain ",
        "strMeasure2": "1 1\/4 cup cold ",
        "strMeasure3": "1\/2 tsp ground roasted ",
        "strMeasure4": "1\/4 tsp ",
        "strMeasure5": "1\/4 tsp dried ",
        "strMeasure6": " ",
        "strMeasure7": " ",
        "strMeasure8": " ",
        "strMeasure9": " ",
        "strMeasure10": " ",
        "strMeasure11": "",
        "strMeasure12": "",
        "strMeasure13": "",
        "strMeasure14": "",
        "strMeasure15": "",
        "dateModified": "2017-02-20 15:19:40"
    }]
};

result.drinks.forEach(function(ingredients){
    var ing = Object.keys(ingredients).reduce(function(a, ele) {
        if (ele.startsWith('strIngredient') && ingredients[ele].trim() != '') {
            if (!a[ingredients.strDrink]) a[ingredients.strDrink] = [];
            a[ingredients.strDrink].push(ingredients[ele]);
        }
        return a;
    }, {});
    console.log(Object.keys(ing)[0] + ': ' + ing[Object.keys(ing)[0]].join(', '));

})
```

Answer (score 0):

**MUCH SIMPLER SOLUTION**
Believing that you have got the successful response from the cocktail API the simple way would be think of replacing the number at the end of drinks[0].strIngredient{num} and checking if the value is null or not, if the value is null you can simply ignore it and print the non null values. I have a code snippet below ::

I have tested it and this works for other parameter

```js
<div class="secondFloat">
            <% for(let i=1;i<=15;i++) { %>
                <% let ingredient = content.drinks[0][`strIngredient${i}`] %>
                <% if(ingredient !== null){ %>
                    <h1><%=ingredient%></h1>
                <%} %>
            <%} %>
```

in the JSON as well.
HOPE THIS HELPS!!!